# DataTable render base on ng-if header

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable

I'm using [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) to change a normal table into a DataTable

In my table, I have AngularJS `ng-if` to change column position

My HTML code

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th ng-if="pos-index == 0">Position</th> <!--pos-index = 0, render column here-->
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th ng-if="pos-index == 1">Position</th> <!--pos-index = 1, render column here-->
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
</table>
```

My JS

```
$scope['pos-index'] = 1;
var t = ('#example').DataTable({
  columns: [
    data: "name",
    data: "office",
    data: "age",
    data: "salary"
    //How to render Position column base on its pos-index?
  ]
});
```

The other columns render perfectly, but I've no idea how to render the Position column. I tried to create 2 postion columns like this

```
columns: [
    data: "name",
    data: "position"
    data: "office",
    data: "age",
    data: "position"
    data: "salary"
  ]
```

And did this

```
if ($scope['pos-index'] === 0) {
  t.column(1).visible(true);
  t.column(4).visible(false);
} else {
  t.column(1).visible(false);
  t.column(4).visible(true);
}
```

But it didn't work.

Any idea for my case?

Comment: you cant access the `pos-index` like this `$scope.pos-index` and try like this `$scope['pos-index']`

Comment: Fixed it, but again, how can I render position column base on that $scope['pos-index]?

Comment: change the variable name!

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Yeah, Cannot read property style of undefined. I know this because DataTable doesnt have enough header to render the cell